# Level curves in ArcGIS map - elevation - topography

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online, elevation, topography

I am using the ArcGIS web map and need to add a contour map (level curves for Uruguay) to perform a topography analysis. I have seen that in the ArcGIS Online search engine there are some maps of this style for some countries or regions.

How can I make one for Uruguay?

Should I do it in the desktop version and then upload it to ArcGIS Web Map or I can do it online directly?

Comment: Have you tried either/both of the options that you are considering?  If both, which did you find easier?  If both, which result did you like better?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the SRTM data, using earth explorer platform (https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/). You will have a 1-arc-second resolution DSM for Uruguay and can work this around with ArcGis or Qgis to generate de level curves that you need.

I recommend you to use a 50m resolution on contour level, that's a good proven threshold for SRTM data quality.

If Uruguay has any DSM data with better quality, you could use to.

This video can help you.
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiPlODjjMbzAhVQrpUCHXr8AYAQwqsBegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dq3iblCHGoZk&usg=AOvVaw0g7M2sDnhpcaebJAY44pMW